# Private local wiki for structured math journal?

Tags: math, markdown, wiki

I want to setup a private wiki to keep a structured journal with mathematical notes. It should be as simple as possible.

Here are the requirements:

1. Simple. As simple as possible.
2. Support math. Ideally markdown + mathjax/katex, since that's what I typically use to write math notes.
3. Good search. It should have a search feature that I can use to quickly locate content based on keywords.
4. Text-based. I want to track the whole thing with git.
5. Instant preview, as I write, including math equations.

Answer (score 2):

[Tiddlywiki](https://tiddlywiki.com) seems to fit the bill.

It is a browser based local wiki that can run either directly from a single HTML file, or from a node.js instance, possibly allowing to use git with the text files.

It has good builtin tagging and searching capabilites along with extensive customizability.

It uses by default a local flavor of wiki markup, but can also use markdown.

Using the [Mathjax](https://tiddlywiki.com/#MathJax%20Plugin%20by%20Martin%20Kantor) plugin it can store math formulas

Comment: TiddlyWiki is really cool, but the interface is so messy, I can't use it.