# How to organize math notes?

Tags: linux, note-taking, math, markdown, latex

I need to organize all of my math notes. I would like to create a sort of library of notes, where a note can link other notes and each note is stored in plain text format (for example, Markdown + Katex/Mathjax) because I want to git track the whole thing.

Whatever the format, there should be an editor available with instant-preview. Also it should be easy to export individual notes or groups of note to publishable formats like PDF and HTML.

All the notes should be quickly searchable by keywords.

I don't need mobile support.

I am open to suggestions. I'm on Linux, but browser-based apps are welcome, as long as they can run offline.

**Note:** I recently posted [Private local wiki for structured math journal?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/49826/8060), which was specific to wiki. Here I am looking for alternatives *not* involving wiki.

Comment: You've mentioned how this differs from [Private local wiki for structured math journal?](/q/49826/185). But how is this different from the other question you've asked: [Text-based note taking applicationg with solid math support and good organization](/q/49790/185)? To me it looks all 3 would match one question, making the format optional (unless you really need 3 different applications). Apart from that, you didn't mention what OS it should run on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [a long blog post](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-2/#) by a guy who uses SVG Editor [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) to quickly draw illustrations for Math lecture notes. It has an "Export to Latex" feature which is hidden inside the "Print as PDF" dialog.
He also uses Vim and git I think. Linux only.

See discussion on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19768012) (~100 comments) for more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The standard option for math notes is, of course, LaTeX and you can use the hyperref package for linking and for example ag for searching.
There are many editor that include instant preview, but you can also add that to any editor using latexmk. Though instant preview is something I tend to avoid because it distracts from the structure instead of the formatting.

If you prefer a more markdown-like syntax, tagging with keywords, export to html, pdf, odt,... http://orgmode.org/ by itself convinced many people to learn to use emacs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [MarkDown](https://www.markdownguide.org/getting-started/) syntax with something like [MathJax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214793/mathjax-jsmath-alternatives) integrated.

5 years later, we can use [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) to organize various kinds of notes (both Scientific and Technology related) as it [comes with MathJax already built in](https://medium.com/beyond-productivity/using-mathjax-in-obsidian-c57640af11ec). [Here](https://help.obsidian.md/Editing+and+formatting/Advanced+formatting+syntax#Math) is a link to their math part of the documentation.

However, if you do not want to be tied to one specific application, [Github has also support for MathJax](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/writing-mathematical-expressions) syntax natively meaning you can omit Obsidian (or switch to your preferred markdown editor) and use a plain GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Obsidian currently. Are you a user? If so, I'd be curious to know which plugins you use.

Comment: Yes, I am using it on a daily basis, and the only plugins I am missing from the default version are https://github.com/OliverBalfour/obsidian-pandoc for exporting to various kinds of formats and the https://github.com/ganesshkumar/obsidian-table-editor for working with tables.

Comment: Any tips for faster math note taking? I've been toying with https://github.com/artisticat1/obsidian-latex-suite and it seems pretty neat (it's the only active community plugin I have at the moment).

Comment: I've seen this https://github.com/Canna71/obsidian-mathpad in action and it looks quite fine, however if you want to make your notes typed fast, you rather write by hand and rewrite to obsidian later ;)  Also this reddit might help https://www.reddit.com/r/ObsidianMD/comments/z21x53/how_u_take_math_notes_effectively/